# cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget not cancelling an outstanding performSelector:withDelay

Tags: ios

I am using a `UIWebView` and don't want the navigation bar to appear unless the user taps anywhere on the screen that isn't a link.
So I have this code to display the navigation bar after a delay:

```
- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender  
{      
.... 
[self performSelector:@selector(showNavigationBar) withObject:self afterDelay:0.2]; 
}
```

I'm not calling `showNavigationBar` immediately when the tap handler is invoked because the user might have tapped on a link in which case the  tap hander is called *before* `UIWebView` `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`, so if I hid the navigation bar in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` it would flash momentarily onto the screen.
So instead I set it to display after a delay which gives time for the following code to execute within `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` (and if the user didn't tap on a link `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` isn't called and the navigation bar is displayed, as it should be in that case).

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType  
{ 
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(showNavigationBar) object:nil];
...
```

However this isn't working, I've increased the delay time to several seconds and can confirm `cancelPreviousPerformRequestWithTarget` is getting called before the navigation bar has been displayed, but when the specified time elapses the bar displays. `cancelPreviousPerformRequestWithTarget` is having no effect.

Does anybody know why its not working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of that `+ (void)cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector object:(id)anArgument` method there is this sentence :

> This method removes perform requests only in the current run loop, not all run loops.

If I'm interpreting it correctly it would mean that you need to cancel your action in the same run loop that you launched it. Which is clearly not what you want to do.

A way to go around this would be to have a flag that `showNavigationBar` would have to check to see if it should proceed or abort.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Is there a cancel variant that works for all run loops? I tried this but it doesn't work either:  [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop ]cancelPerformSelector:@selector(showNavigationBar) target:self argument:nil];

Comment: @Piepants I don't think so, but that doesn't mean there is not.

Comment: Had the same issue and flagging is the way to go!

Answer (score 16):

Your perform doesn't match your cancel. In the perform you're passing self as the object:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showNavigationBar) withObject:self afterDelay:0.2];
```

In the cancel you're passing nil as the object:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(showNavigationBar) object:nil];
```

They don't match, so the delayed perform should not be canceled.

Comment: I just did like that with no luck. So I tried to remove all requests: [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self]; Now it works like a charm.

Comment: To expand on what Dave said, withObject in the original call is for method parameters. If there are none, then it should be nil. If there are some then showNavigationBar needs a colon : after it and the first parameter is the first withObject.

Comment: To conclude: passed object must match. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(showNavigationBar) object:self];
```

That worked for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Not sure why but works like a charm for me.**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    });
```